# If $f/g$ is of bounded variation, then $f$ and $g$ are of bounded variation?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f,g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ are functions such that $f/g$ is of bounded variation. Is it true that $f$ and $g$ are of bounded variation? They should because $g^2d(f/g)= gdf - f dg$, but I cannot write a nice proof. I think my argument might work for the reverse implication instead.

Comment: Are there cadlag functions which are not of bounded variation?

Comment: @PaulFrost You are right, forget about that part

Comment: What about the pair $(f,g) = (f,f)$ when $f$ is not of bounded variation? Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro perfect counter-example. Thank you. Do you have an idea what to add to make the statement correct? What about $f/g$ is strictly increasing? Or $f.g$ is also of bounded variation?

Comment: Off-hand I don't know, but definitely not $f/g$ strictly increasing since you could simply use something like $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{1\,+\,x^2}$ for a non-BV $f$ (change $1 + x^2$ a bit so that $f/g$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]).$ If you have access to a university library, maybe something in [this dissertation](https://www.proquest.com/openview/602c3b527d8c41d568cb14c4d43d51a8) or [this book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/038794642X) will help -- both have a nontrivial amount of material on BV functions.

Comment: It just occurred to me (as I was leaving for today, but I returned quickly to mention it) that instead of trying to think of ways to avoid variations cancelling themselves out by division, it might be easier to think of ways to avoid variations cancelling themselves out additively by possibly making use of $\log f/g = \log f - \log g.$

Comment: Choose $h$ to be BV and $g$ to not be BV, and let $f = gh$. Then $f/g = h$ is BV, but $f, g$ are not. No restrictions just on $h$ are going to prevent this. The only way to deduce BV for $f, g$ from that of $f/g$ is to require that either $f$ or $g$ is BV in the first place. Then you can conclude the other is BV. There are no "two-for-one" deals here where you get two functions must be BV for the price of only proving one other function is BV.